# Change image in exe file

Tags: exe, desktop-application

I have an exe file, when it is executed, has an image in the program interface. I want to modify that image to replace it with another image. Can I get the path to the image that the exe file unpacks into the temp directory when it's executed, or is the image accessed directly from the exe file and I can't modify it?

I tried resource hacker but when open the exe file with it, I can't find the image I need, it not there. So I need other solution, like modify the image when the exe is running.
The exe file could have been written in C++.